# Does Smart UV unwrap preserve the area of each face in the mapping

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to unwrap an object and have the UV mapping preserve the relative area of each face. Can any of the unwrapping options be configured to ensure that the relative area of each face is preserved?

For example, when Smart UV unwrap is used on a cylinder, the mapping shown below results. This appears to maintain the relative area. However, it is not clear if the relative areas are preserved. Are there UV unwrap options that will ensure the relative areas?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on "relative area" please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you unwrap with Smart UV unwrap it does not skew or stretch (you will get a lot of seams though) if you apply textures to it. If you mark seams but do it wonky, you will get skewing. You also have to keep in mind the resolution of the texture because it will appear to skew if the resolution is too low.